# Django static files not loading even with STATICFILES_DIR set to correct path

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

I've looked at so many similar questions on Stack overflow and other websites but I cant seem to figure out why my static files aren't loading.

I have created my base template based on a tutorial online, and it should work like magic. But my static files arent rendering with the view. When I go to the developer console on chrome I see that the css and js files are not found. the exact error is:

```
> 127.0.0.1/:8 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> 127.0.0.1/:117 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> 127.0.0.1/:118 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/popper.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> 127.0.0.1/:119 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my base template:

```html
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Django Forms{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    {% block stylesheets %}
    {% endblock stylesheets %}

</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark" >
        <div class="container" >
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Blog App</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-controls="mainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu" >
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{user.username}}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My account</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" >Change password</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" >
        <ol class = "breadcrumb my-4">
            {% block breadcrumb %}
            {% endblock %}
        </ol>

            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% endblock body %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'widget_tweaks',

    'accounts',
    'blog',


]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   #  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'myformapp', 'static','js')
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

My folder structure:

```
Formproject
|___________myformapp
|___________accounts
|___________blog
|___________myformapp
              |__________templates
                           |__________includes
                           |__________base.html
                           |__________other_templates.html
               |_____________init__.py
               |___________settings.py
               |___________urls.py
____________static
____________static_root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was a basic mistake on my part.

on my template i had done up my `<link>` tag as follows

```
<link rel = "stylesheets" src="file source here">
```

while it should have been

```
<link rel = "stylesheets" href="file source here">
```

such a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your *templates* and *static* folders are not under the same root, it might be the problem. Anyway, try adding this to the project's *settings.py*:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Then, use your CSS files in HTML:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}">
```

This should work fine.

Comment: I've added {%load static%} on the top of the template file.. Are u asking me to put it right before the <link> tag?

Comment: I changed the path for the static and templates folder. added the templates and static folders under the same root. didn't work